# Insert data from one table to another in joined table

Tags: php, sql, insert

This sends "customers.id" to another php file :

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="createworkorder.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Add Workorder</a>';
```

This pulls the id date just sent :

```
$id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }

    if ( null==$id ) {
        header("Location: customers.php");
    }
```

This looks at values/ and inserts data from extra workorder table form post :

```
$id          = $POST['name'];
        $date        = $_POST['date'];
        $installer   = $_POST['installer'];
        $salesman    = $_POST['salesman'];
        $category    = $_POST['category'];
        $status      = $_POST['status'];
if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO workorder (date, installer, salesman, category, status) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array( $id,$date,$installer,$salesman,$category,$status));

            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: workorders.php");
        }
<form class="form-horizontal" action="createworkorder.php" method="post">

                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($dateError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">Date</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="date" type="text"  placeholder="Date" value="<?php echo !empty($date)?$date:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($dateError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $dateError;?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($installerError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">Installer</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="installer" type="text" placeholder="Installer" value="<?php echo !empty($installer)?$installer:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($installerError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $installerError;?></span>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

for some odd reason, it looks like everything executes(no errors), but no data shows up in my workorders table.  This is what is supposed to happen

1. Pull customers.id from user selection, and store into workorder.name
2. Pull extra information(date/installer/salesman/etc) from form, and use all of the data to insert into workorder table.

Does anyone see if there is something dumb causing this not to happen?

Comment: I don't understand where the POST data is coming from.  May be obvious, but I'm not connecting the dots there.  Please explain.

Comment: the "id" is coming from a seperate php file that deals with the customers table  that "id" is to be inserted into the workorder table as "name".  I can use the web developer tools in firefox to see that it is pulling the correct information from that page, so I am thinking the problem has to do with something with my insert statement?

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I spoke PHP, but are you inserting too many variables?

Specifically, in the code below, is including `$id` throwing it off?  If you have to include `$id`, should you modify the `INSERT` query to include a spot for the id?

`$q->execute(array( $id,$date,$installer,$salesman,$category,$status));`

Comment: I included $id so that the "name" field could be inserted, but I removed to test, still to no avail